# Is there a correlation between numbers with record totient valence and the factorials?

Tags: number-theory

For example, there are 10 values of $n$ such that $\phi(n) = 24$, and that's more than for any smaller, positive integer. It's not true of 120 but it is true of 720. I haven't verified it for 5040.

Comment: +1 here you can find an explicite list: [Wolfram:TotientValenceFunction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientValenceFunction.html) and OEIS provides a big list of values you can check: http://oeis.org/A007374/b007374.txt

Answer (score 1):

The numbers that set new records do have decreasing (well, non-increasing) exponents in the prime factorization. This often means that there is a subsequence of the same type as Ramanujan's "Superior Highly Composite" numbers, but it may take real work to construct those in detail.

---

```
           1           2                     1 =  1 
           2           3                     2 = 2
           4           4                     4 = 2^2
           8           5                     8 = 2^3
          12           6                    12 = 2^2 * 3
          24          10                    24 = 2^3 * 3
          48          11                    48 = 2^4 * 3
          72          17                    72 = 2^3 * 3^2
         144          21                   144 = 2^4 * 3^2
         240          31                   240 = 2^4 * 3 * 5
         432          34                   432 = 2^4 * 3^3
         480          37                   480 = 2^5 * 3 * 5
         576          38                   576 = 2^6 * 3^2
         720          49                   720 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5
        1152          54                  1152 = 2^7 * 3^2
        1440          72                  1440 = 2^5 * 3^2 * 5
        2880          98                  2880 = 2^6 * 3^2 * 5
        4320         126                  4320 = 2^5 * 3^3 * 5

        5040          93                  5040 = 2^4 * 3^2 * 5 * 7
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

---

Comment: agrees with oeis. good.

Answer (score 1):

There is a correlation but it's not as interesting as you might expect.

As you already know, $n! = \prod_{i = 1}^n i$. You also already know that the totient function is multiplicative conditioned on coprimality.

So, given a prime $p$ and a positive integer exponent $\alpha$, we have $\phi(p^\alpha) = p^{\alpha - 1}(p - 1)$. In order for an integer to have a totient valence, it must either be a number of that form or the product of numbers of that form. Some integers can't be represented that way at all, they're "nontotients." Other integers can be represented that way in more than one way, like 24, for which we have $(5 - 1)(7 - 1) = (3 - 1)(13 - 1) = (5 - 1)(3^{2 - 1}(3 - 1)) =$ etc.

Clearly $n!$ has numbers that are one less than primes and powers of primes among its factors. But it also has nontotients among its factors, though these can contribute to the valence (e.g., $2 \times 14 = 29 - 1$. If $n$ is a nontotient, $n!$ is unlikely to set a record for totient valence, but otherwise, it might.

T. D. Noe and Donovan Johnson have computed a list of numbers with record-setting totient valence up to 3832012800, see http://oeis.org/A097942.

Comment: Last line of penultimate paragraph, you mean "If $n$ is a nontotient, $n!$ is unlikely to set a record for totient valence, but otherwise, it might" right?